# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, server-error

I have tried anything i could regarding this issue by setting the custom error as OFF. Basically what i am trying to do is deploying my application to a server however i keep getting this error, which stops me on accessing the application. its my first time seeing this error.

I could really do with some help.
 Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you just update packages? Does it run on your pc? I've had similar errors when dependencies were using different .NET versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might help you.

select the `System.Web.Http.Webhost` assembly in your references and alter the 'Copy Local' property to True.
This site might give you an idea :  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the binding information in my web.config (or app.config) allows you to move forward with your project after a NuGet package update whacks your application and gives you the System.Net.Http error.

Set newVersion="4.0.0.0"